# How can I achieve a "formation move" in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the first picture, the three selected units (Ultralisks) have been given a movement order to a point, and are converging on that point. In the second, the three units in motion (Overlords) are moving to roughly the designated point, but are staying in the formation they were in.

[image: onepoint]
[image: formation]

<sup>The orders given here were actually patrol orders, just so they showed up in the screenshots.</sup>

I want to be able to reliably achieve the second outcome, movement in formation. However, the game chooses between the two movement types seemingly at random, making it rather difficult. How can I reliably move units in formation?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking about how to make them move in formation like in the second picture?

Comment: Very clear what he's asking to anyone familiar with Blizzard RTS games. He wants the units to remain in the formation they started in while moving and when they reach their destination, rather than each independently trying to get to the point targeted.

Comment: The original question was not as clear as it is now.

Answer (score 3):

Formation move is a feature of air units.  I'm not sure there is a formation move for ground units in Starcraft 2.  You can test this technique with ground units and see if it applies.

Take, for example, magic box mutas: